# Create excel file through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Does anyone know how to create excel and ppt files through the MS Graph API?  We're trying to leverage the MS Graph API to create word/excel/ppt files on a button click and while we found how to create word files, the excel and powerpoint files created are corrupted even with a success response from the api.  The end point below works for the word files.  We've been just working with the graph api explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) for now.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{Drive ID}/root/children/ 

Request Body:
{
  "name": "FileTest6.docx",
  "file":{
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**PowerPoint files**

PowerPoint files could be created via [DriveItem upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint, for example:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/sample.pptx:/content
```

or

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
{
  "name": "Sample.pptx",
  "file":{ }
}
```

**Excel files**

With excel files the situation is a bit different since the content of the excel file to be uploaded *needs to be provided explicitly*.

For ASP.NET Core application the following solution could be considered:

- create empty Excel document via [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) (see `CreateWorkbook` example below)
- upload it via [DriveItem upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

C# example

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    CreateWorkbook(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var driveItem = await graphClient.Me
            .Drive
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath("SampleWorkbook1.xlsx")
            .Content
            .Request()
            .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
    }
```

where

```
public static void CreateWorkbook(Stream stream)
{

    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    var spreadsheetDocument =
        SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    var workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    var worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    var sheet = new Sheet()
        {Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet"};
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
 }
```

Comment: creating empty docx or xlsx files appears to work fine using the first method given for pptx

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.