# How to Create a Excelfile in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a application to work with office 365 Excel in sharepoint with help of `Microsoft Graph REST API V1.0`. With following code I am able to create a sub-directory in root directory. How can i add Excel file to my root directory.

```
var driveItem = new DriveItem
{
    Name = name,
    Folder = new Folder
    {
    },
};

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().AddAsync(driveItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates an excel workbook and adds it to your root directory. I have tested it and it works fine.

[Drive item end point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) can be used to upload the file.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207620/create-excel-file-through-microsoft-graph-api). Please refer it for more details

The following code will create the excel file

```
public static void CreateWorkbook(Stream stream)
        {

            // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
            var spreadsheetDocument =
                SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
            var workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
            var worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
            var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            var sheet = new Sheet()
            { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
            // Close the document.
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
        }
```

Use the following to upload the above-created file in C#

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CreateWorkbook(stream);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var driveItem = await client.Me
                        .Drive
                        .Root
                        .ItemWithPath("SampleWorkbook1.xlsx")
                        .Content
                        .Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
            }
```