# 0 Byte file when uploading an Excel document to SharePoint online using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, npoi

I am attempting to upload an Excel document created using the NPOI library to a SharePoint Online site using the Microsoft Graph API.

When I write the Excel file to my local machines user directory, I'm able to open the generated `TestExcelUpload.xslx` file without issue and see the *'ColOne', 'ColTwo', 'ColThree'* entries.

However, when I upload the Excel file to the SharePoint Online site, I can see the file gets created, but when I attempt to open it I get the error message `Sorry, we couldn't find 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Technology/Shared Documents/Tool/Data/TestExcelUpload.xlsx'. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?`. If I download the file, I can see it has a Size of 0 bytes. So I think the issue is to do with how I am doing the upload - I attempted to follow the sample from the Microsoft docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?msclkid=5dab86cad12711ec91c842a089f27412&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp.

The code below is where I am with it:

1. Create a simple excel workbook using the NPOI library
2. Use a file stream to write the excel workbook to my local directory (I initially just used this to rule out a problem creating the workbook with NPOI)
3. Use the Graph API to get the document path I want to upload to, read the excel workbook into a memory stream and then use the Graph API again to upload the memory stream to the path as the content.

Would anyone be able to tell me where I might be going wrong?

```cs
public async Task ExcelUploadToSharePointTest()
{
    // 1. Create basic excel .xlsx workbook using NPOI v2.5.6  
    var testColumnData = new List<string> { "ColOne", "ColTwo", "ColThree" };

    var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    var sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet();
    var row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);

    for (var i = 0; testColumnData.Count > i; i++)
    {
        row1.CreateCell(i).SetCellValue(testColumnData[i]);
    }

    // 2. Write workbook to local user directory - works
    await using (var fileSteam = new FileStream($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)}/TestExcelUpload.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
    {
        workbook.Write(fileSteam, true);
    }

    // 3. Write workbook to SharePoint online, by saving to memory stream and uploading using Graph API - not working
    var siteBase = await _graphServiceClient.Sites
        .GetByPath("/sites/Technology", "company.sharepoint.com")
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    var rootFolder = _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteBase.Id].Drive.Root;

    await using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.Write(memoryStream, true);

        await rootFolder.ItemWithPath("Tool/Data/TestExcelUpload.xlsx").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you need to set `memoryStream.Position` to 0.

When you call `workbook.Write(memoryStream, true)` then the current position within the stream is same as the length of the stream and therefore zero bytes are uploaded.

```
await using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    workbook.Write(memoryStream, true);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    await rootFolder.ItemWithPath("Tool/Data/TestExcelUpload.xlsx").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: Your exactly right, this was my problem. I just stumbled across the same solution here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392098/3371045). I added `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` after the `workbook.Write(memoryStream, true);` call and it all started to work. I've never used MemoryStream before so I'll have to remember this. Many thanks for your help.